# Hide private IP address

Tags: cisco, nat, ospf, packet-tracer, private-vlan

[image]

DS has 7 VLANs and 7 DHCP pools respectively. There are 3 trunk links to 3 access layer switchs to share VLANs. Its VLAN interfaces and DHCP pools:

```
ip dhcp pool vlan10
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.10.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
ip dhcp pool vlan20
 network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.20.1
ip dhcp pool vlan30
 network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.30.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
ip dhcp pool vlan40
 network 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.40.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
ip dhcp pool vlan50
 network 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.50.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
ip dhcp pool vlan60
 network 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.60.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1001
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1002
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan30
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1003
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan40
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1004
 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan50
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1005
 ip address 192.168.50.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan60
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1006
 ip address 192.168.60.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan100
 mac-address 0060.70dd.1007
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
```

I use single OSPF for DS, RT-GW and Internet. All networks are linked but I want to hide private IP addresses when they go outside from RT-GW. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use NAT on RT-GW:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 ip address 203.0.113.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
!
ip nat inside source list 101 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 overload
!
access-list 101 permit tcp any host 8.8.8.8
```

Result:

```
RT-GW#sh ip nat trans
Pro  Inside global     Inside local       Outside local      Outside global
icmp 203.0.113.2:5     192.168.30.11:5    8.8.8.8:5          8.8.8.8:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is what Network Address Translation (NAT) is meant to do and would be required in your scenario to reach the internet while using RFC1918 IP addresses anyway.

Comment: OSPF will not work across NAT, which the question seems to indicate that the OP wants.

Comment: Ah, perhaps. I assumed 'single OSPF for DS, RT-GW' meant OSPF neighbor between DS and RT-GW. Though it could mean between RT-GW and Internet (ISP), I suppose, or perhaps all three, though I don't see any need for OSPF between RT-GW and an ISP connection/router. If NAT is used on RT-GW, then there is only 1 route (default) from the ISP connection. Realistically, in this design, OSPF is not even needed between DS and RT-GW though it may be convenient if the network changes frequently or has more complexity.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer I use the router named Internet to simulate Internet. If there is not OSPF, do you mean I should use RIP/EIGRP/static instead? Should I use subinterface for inter-VLAN routing in this case?

Comment: @chancuockhanh, routing protocols are broken by NAT. Routing protocols want to advertise the networks, not a NAT.

Comment: @chancuockhanh, remember that NAT is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4 until IPv6 is ubiquitous and restores the IP end-to-end paradigm where every host has a unique public address. You get security from firewalls, not NAT. You need a firewall between your network and the public Internet, otherwise if your RT-GW is compromised, it knows about all the internal networks, and then the attacker has access to all of them.

Comment: @RonMaupin This information is really helpful to me. Thankyou!

Comment: @chancuockhanh you already appear to be using vlan subinterfaces on the DS device. I don't see any need for a dynamic routing protocol at all in the diagrammed network unless you expect it to change in design or grow frequently. For a network with one gateway device and a basic internet connection, you don't need any dynamic routing protocol. You can connect the internet service to a firewall, then the switch to the firewall protected network and have the firewall do the NAT for IPv4 to allow internet access for your client devices. The firewall can also do access control for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer I removed OSPF, put a firewall between DS and RT-GW also. But packets from VLANs don't seem to reach the firewall. I set default-router of DS is the firewall's interface connecting to it and default-gateway of PCs are IP addresses of VLAN interfaces on DS. Particularly, PC in VLAN 10 tracerts to private interface of the firewall, its packets stop at 192.168.10.1 (IP addr of interface VLAN 10 on DS).

Comment: You need a network between the DS and Firewall and the firewall needs a static route to know how to reach the IP networks on the DS. You should start with an updated design document and post a new question if the design has changed and you can't figure it out.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer sorry for the late answer. I solved my problem but could not have time to check comments because I had to finish its document to submit as my homework. I changed ASA5505 to ASA5506. ASA5506 supports dynamic routing making me realize I need routes between them. I tried with 5505 again with static routing and it worked. Thankyou for helping me out.

Comment: @chancuockhanh you should select an answer for your question to mark it complete.